# Excel 2016, how do I extract a value not charted, which is adjacent to the cell used as a chart value?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

For example, say I have a chart with these data, where **DESCRIPTION** and **COST** are charted as a Series, but **MONTH** is not:

`/  A         B                C`

`1  MONTH     DESCRIPTION      COST`

`2  May       Planning Cost    $100`

`3  June      Lodging          $550`

`4  July      Pet Care         $250`

Is it possible using VBA to reference the underlying value of **MONTH** for a given series' data point in the chart, even though it's not displayed in the chart series itself?

Comment: You could always just grab it from the source data - where are you trying to display the value? Why not just plot Month and Description on the X axis?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Just expand the Horizontal Axis labels to include column A.

[image: img1]

Comment: I mean to say programmatically. I want to be able to reference the Month value so I can add logic as I iterate through the values, e.g. if I wanted to change a property like color based on the Month, but without cluttering the graph with additional labels. I mean I could incorporate the Month into a calculated field and use that, but I'd rather reference cell A2's value (in)directly.

Comment: @DarthContinent You'd have to do it through a work around, start by looping through the series values which simultaneously loops through the table on your worksheet to find the adjacent month value.

Comment: That's my difficulty, I can loop through the chart series, but I'm unclear on how to acquire the row referenced by the series so that I could then grab the value from say cell A2. Is there a property of the series I'm missing that specifies the row/cell?

Comment: I think I found it! `Series.Formula` captures the cell info in the formula bar at each iteration of series. If you can help me with a VBA snippet that takes a formula and parses out the cell coordinates, I'll gladly award you the answer.

Comment: @DarthContinent Ooh interesting. Let me give it a shot. You could possibly split out of the column you need from the formula.